# How to correctly handle the observable returned when making a HTTP request with Axios using Nestjs HTTP module

Tags: node.js, rxjs, axios, nestjs

I am trying to figure out how to go about making a http request using Axios and the Nestjs framework.  In the nest documentation it gives a high level overview of the process but doesn't go into detail on how to go about handling the Observable returned when making a request using axios.

I am making a request to an API using mutual SSL authentication. I had a certificate issue and my request failed however no exception was thrown and the controller returned a 200 ok with no data.  I discovered this when I commented all the rxjs code out and did a axios.get(...).toPromise().  when I did this I suddenly had a full stacktrace and a exception was thrown.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  Should I maybe put the catchError block before the map block?

my code:

```
getRegistrationStatus(msisdn: string): Observable<AxiosResponse> {        
  return this.httpService.get(`${this.API_BASE_URL}/vb/registrationStatus?MSISDN=${msisdn}`)
    .pipe(            
      map(res => res.data),
      catchError(e => {
        throw new HttpException(e.statusText, e.status);
      })            
    );
}
```

my HTTP Module/axios config:

```
HttpModule.register({
  timeout: 20000,
  validateStatus: () => true,
  httpsAgent: new Agent({
    ca: readFileSync(process.env.va_ca),
    keepAlive: false,        
    cert: readFileSync(process.env.va_cert),
    key: readFileSync(process.env.va_key),
    passphrase: process.env.va_passphrase
  })
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend to return an Observable that only emits the actual data of the request and not an `AxiosResponse`. It's also often advisable to handle http errors directly in the functions that creates the http request (`getRegistrationStatus`) and not where this function is called / consumed.

```ts
// You could replace 'RegistrationStatus' with 'any' if you don't have a 
// corresponding interface, but it's better to create one if you can
getRegistrationStatus(msisdn: string): Observable<RegistrationStatus> {       
  return this.httpService.get(`${this.API_BASE_URL}/vb/registrationStatus?MSISDN=${msisdn}`)
    .pipe(            
      map(res => res.data),
      catchError(this.handleError<RegistrationStatus>(null)) // <- provide a default value on errors e.g. null           
    );
}

handleError<T>(result?: T) {
  return (error: AxiosError<any>): Observable<T> => {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);

    return of(result as T);
  }
}
```

Call the function and subscribe.

```ts
getRegistrationStatus(msisdn: string).subscribe(regStatus => {
  // regStatus will be null when an error occured
  console.log('registration status:', regStatus);
})
```

Answer (score -2):

axiosInstance is supposed to return a Promise, not an Observable.

Comment: The nestjs HTTP module transforms the axios response as an observable...

Comment: Sorry I didn’t understand you’re using a service from nestjs, which wraps the axios in observable.